# How do I implement Eigen's recommendation to disable parallelisation / multithreading -- where and how many pre-processor tokens?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, eigen3

I have a small programme that uses `Eigen`'s matrices in multiple cpp class files, let's say for a MWE in the `main.cpp` and `MyClass.h.`

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <parallel/algorithm>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

Eigen::MatrixXd hello = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(1000,2); // make a large matrix so that 
//Eigen would want to use parallelisation

vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> my_container(1000,Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(1000,1000)); //make a large
//container so __gnu_parallel would want to use parallelisation

//a parallel loop here

__gnu_parallel::for_each(my_container.begin(),my_container.end(),[&hello]
(const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXd>& MyMat){
    MyMat * hello; //dense matrix multiplication which Eigen would parallelise
    });

    return 0;
}
```

### What Eigen recommends:

Per Eigen's own description [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html), I believe that dense matrix multiplication and the parallel nature of the `for_each` loop would interfere in a manner such that I would have to choose between either Eigen performing multithreading in which case I could switch from the `__gnu_parallel` namespace to the `__gnu_sequential` namespace or turn off Eigen's parallelisation.

Given that my matrices tend to be smaller (mostly) than the ones used in this example, I would prefer to keep my loops through the `STL` containers parallel, so I would like to stick to `__gnu_parallel::for_each`, `__gnu_parallel::transform` etc.

### What I need to do

Therefore, I believe I need to define a pre-processor token:

```
#define EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE
```

### My Question

1. Is this reasoning correct? I.e. If I did not define this token, would `__gnu_parallel` and `Eigen`'s parallelisation interfere with each other? My working hypothesis is yes.
2. Where do I place the token definition, before or after `#include <Eigen/Dense>`?
3. Regarding a header file defining classes and methods `MyClass.h`, where I have `MyClass::MyMethod` using `Eigen`'s matrices having a separate include for the Eigen library, would I need separate tokens (preferably with a guard) along the lines of the following code snippet?

Code

```
#ifndef EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE
#define EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE
#endif
#include <Eigen/Dense>
    class MyClass 
            { //code using Eigen's matrices here};
```

### Background

For some background, I have seen this in one of Eigen's headers:

```
#if (defined _OPENMP) && (!defined EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE)
#define EIGEN_HAS_OPENMP
#endif.
```